# sql substitution in ssis task in texteditor

Tags: ssis

I have to update a pkg; specifically **a DFT task uses some sql to imports data from source (s) to a target table (t)**
In the extraction query some columns are not cast properly I am getting loads of warning issue on the metadata

```
s.col1 = varchar(255)
t.col1 = char(1)
```

Even if the s.col1 has 1 as max value so the import will not fail

Unfortunately the pkg is *monolithic* and I don’t want to rework it adding derived columns or applying substring etc to the extraction query.
I was wondering if opening the pkg in text mode and looking for the DFT entry as

```
<DTS:Property DTS:Name="ObjectName">DFT - XYZ</DTS:Property>
```

I can just copy and past the new sql where I see the old sql, or this could lead to some issue (at the end) the *hard coded* I've found (another bad practice...) is in plain text... so I can update it with the fix I need and the pkg will run not complain at design time with warnings...
Any advice is appreciated.
Mario
ps I don't want to go using disable the validation on dft task (there are loads of them)

Comment: If I'm reading your question: you have metadata defined that is causing warnings. Your assumption is that by changing the source query, those will go away. *Maybe* it will. It really depends on what the metadata currently looks like, what the new will be, etc. Just be sure you have a valid copy of the package before you go spelunking

Comment: IMHO ... avoid shortcuts - you eventually end up paying more - sometimes that also includes your own reputation, because this is your baby now. Explain the situation to your management and suggest for a good fix. If it's monolithic and the package is going to be used for some more time, even fix that part - even if partially. Sell on the points of better maintenance, performance. Management loves when people take upon themselves to clean the mess.